# how to specify and change object in object of useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

```js
    const [info, setInfo] = useState({
        idx: 1,
        user: {
            name: ""
        }
    });
```

```js
    function handle(e) {
        setInfo(prev => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
    }
```

```js
     <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handle(e)} name="idx" /> // works!
     <input type="text" onChange={(e) => handle(e)} name="user.name" /> // NOT work
```

how can i change **user.name** value of useState as name attribute of text input?

try:
name="user.name"
name="user['name']"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `name` is nested in `user` it would be easier to have an independent `onChange` function, as your current `handle` function will only set top-level keys using `e.target.name`

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => setInfo(prevState => {...prevState, user: {name: e.target.value}})}/>
```